# Integral of an infinite power tower.

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int {\sqrt{x+^{\sqrt{x+^{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdot \cdot \cdot}}}}}}}dx$

How does one approach this problem?

Comment: There might be some problems with the notations...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Sorry. How do you make them look normal?

Comment: The proper approach is to punch the person who asked you in the nose.  There is no reason to expect that there is an elementary indefinite integral.  Maybe you want to define a function $Lok(x)$ as the definite integral from $1$ to $x$.  This is a well defined function for $x \gt 1$.  I doubt you can evaluate it analytically, but numerically should be OK as long as the integrand converges, which I suspect is true for all $x \gt 1$

Comment: One does not approach this problem. One flees from it as quickly as possible!

Comment: The power is on the "$+$" sign, which does not make sense.

Comment: Please @Lok, explain what your notation actually means, otherwise this question makes no sense

Answer (score 4):

This makes sense for $x>0$ (integral is just red herring):

$$y=\sqrt{x+{\sqrt{x+{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\dots}}}}}}$$

$$y=\sqrt{x+y}$$

$$y^2-y-x=0$$

$$y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$

Discard the negative solution and then solve:

$$\int \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}dx$$

Fun fact:

$$2=\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots}}}}}}$$

Comment: What sense does a power on a $+$ sign make?

Comment: @user10354138  I think it’s some glitch in Latex, there is no power after the plus sign, just an endless sequence of roots.

Comment: I'll quote the your TeX: `y=\sqrt{x+^{\sqrt{x+^{\sqrt{`...  which clearly shows the `^` on the +.

Comment: @user10354138 I just copied the text of the problem. The power sign makes no sense, I am going to remove it.

Comment: You are not answering the question, you are answering something else you like. I don't see any point, unless the OP clarifies that yes, this is exactly what they meant

Comment: @YuriyS There are just two possible expressions: It's either $x+\sqrt{x+\dots}$ or $x+^\sqrt{x+...}$. I have solved the problem using the first one not becuase "I like it" but because the second one is **pure nonsense**. If you teach me what the second expression really means, maybe I can solve that one too. And you can always downvote my answer because I did not match the formatiing nonse in the problem with the same kind of nonsense in my answer.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote the answer, but this could very well confuse the future users. You see, the OP called their expression a *power tower*, which is quite different from the nested radical you consider. Likely `^` in their code are not accidental, so it's either they clarify the question, or I would prefer it closed as unclear

Comment: @YuriyS In my opinion, the title mentiones "tower" because if you mess with formatting, the nonsense that it produces really looks like a tower. That's just my opinion though. You can always cast a closing vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch blackpenredpen's video on YouTube for the solution :-https://youtu.be/2opBQJqib-E